# fork() process ... I need help. I have the answers but I do not understand how it is done.

Tags: unix, process, fork

How many different copies of the variable x are there?  what are their values when their process finishes?

```
main (int argc, char ** argv){
    int child = fork()
    int x = 5; 

    if (child == 0) {
       x += 5;
    } else {
        child = fork();
        x += 10; 
        if(child) {
            x += 5;
        }
    }
```

}

I know the answer but can someone help me guid through this?

Answer (score 0):

The fork() function returns 2 times each time is called. 
It creates two processes, returning 0 to the father and another value to the child process.
It means that both condititions will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have framed your question correctly i.e. copies of x (vs no. of address spaces) but here's how fork works:

- every time you call this method, 2 address spaces are created for all
  the statements below it.
- in your case:

  - after "int child = fork()", 2 address spaces are created   and after
    "child = fork()", which will only get executed for parent, parent
    would further break in 2 address spaces
  - so the answer is 3